# Correlation of number of hearts and diamonds of 3 cards drawn from a deck of 52

Tags: correlation

3 cards are drawn from a deck of 52 cards. Let $X$ and $Y$ represent the number of hearts and number of diamonds respectively. Find the correlation of $(X,Y)$.

I know that correlation is defined as $\frac{\mathrm{COV}(X,Y)}{\sigma_{X}\sigma_{Y}}$. 
I also understand that the two random variables are not independent.

Comment: Where are you stuck?  What approaches have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

One (annoying) obstacle (with little pedagogical value) in problems like this is carrying out the combinatorial calculations.  You are going to need information about the bivariate distribution of $(X,Y),$ which is tantamount to knowing how many possible deals of $3$ cards have $X$ hearts and $Y$ diamonds for all possible values of $X$ and $Y$.  Due to the symmetry--there are as many hearts as diamonds in a deck--you only need to compute the values for $Y\ge X$, which gives six nonzero numbers.  Here they are:

```
X   Y   Number of hands
0   0    2600
0   1    4225
0   2    2028
0   3     286
1   1    4394
1   2    1014
------  ---------------
Total:  22100
```

For instance, $2600$ is the number of hands with no hearts or diamonds.  Therefore they are drawn from the 26 remaining cards.  There are $\binom{26}{3} = 2600$ such draws.  As another example, $4225$ is the number of hands with one diamond and no hearts and it equals the number of hands with one heart and no diamonds.  In either case, one card comes from a 13-element set of cards and the other two come from a 26-element set of cards (all the non-heart, non-diamond cards).  The total number of combinations therefore equals $\binom{13}{1}\binom{26}{2} = 4225.$  Similar techniques will yield the other four numbers.

At this point all you need to do is apply the definition of correlation to this distribution.  *That* has some pedagogical merit in confronting you with the details (which can be illuminating) and confirming whether you have truly understood the definition.